# Combining results from two tables into JSON data

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have two tables, `words` and `paragraph`. The `words` table is as below:

```
+----+---------+--------------+--------+
| id | word_no | paragraph_no |  word  |
+----+---------+--------------+--------+
|  1 |    1    |       1      |  hello |
+----+---------+--------------+--------+
|  2 |    2    |       1      |  how   |
+----+---------+--------------+--------+
|  3 |    3    |       1      |  are   |
+----+---------+--------------+--------+
|  4 |    4    |       1      |  you   |
+----+---------+--------------+--------+
```

And the `paragraph` table is as below:

```
+----+--------------+-------------------+
| id | paragraph_no |     paragraph     |
+----+--------------+-------------------+
|  1 |       1      | hello how are you |
+----+--------------+-------------------+
```

I want all the columns from the `words` table WHERE `paragraph_no` is 1 and the paragraph column from paragraph table with the same WHERE clause all in one JSON results. Something like this:

```
{
    "1": [ <-- this is the paragraph number

        "words": [

            {
                "id": "1",
                "word_no": "1",
                "paragraph_no": "1",
                "word": "hello"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "word_no": "2",
                "paragraph_no": "1",
                "word": "how"
            },

            // and so on...

        ],

        "paragraph": [

            {
                "paragraph": "hello how are you"
            }

        ]

    ]
}
```

Please excuse my mock-up but I need something similar to that. My current PHP code to only get the words are:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM words WHERE paragraph_no = 1");

$data = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $data[$row['paragraph_no']][] = $row;

$API_RESULT = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

echo $API_RESULT;
```

Which outputs only the words like this:

```
{
    "1": [ <-- this is the paragraph number

        {
            "id": "1",
            "word_no": "1",
            "paragraph_no": "1",
            "word": "hello"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "word_no": "2",
            "paragraph_no": "1",
            "word": "how"
        },

        // and so on...

    ]
}
```

How can I get my desired JSON output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get your desired structure you need to execute two SQL statements - one for getting all words and one for getting all paragraphs.

```
$result_w = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM words;");
$results_w = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$result_p = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM paragraphs;");
$results_p = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$paragraphs = [];
foreach($results_p as $key => $row) {
  $paragraphs[$row['id']] = $row;
}

$data = [];

foreach($results_w as $key => $row) {
  $p_no = $row['paragraph_no'];
  $data[$p_no]['words'] = $results_w;
  $data[$p_no]['paragraph'] = $paragraphs[$p_no];
}
```

Is your output for `$data` now what you need?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your solution almost works except that now all the words in the table is shown in each paragraph JSON array. What I mean is, it's showing me something like: `paragraph1 -> all the words in the table`, `paragraph2 -> all the words in the table`. However what I want is something like: `paragraph1 -> only paragraph 1 words`, `paragraph2 -> only paragraph2 words`. I even tried to add a WHERE clause to the sql query but no luck. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: I actually realized that the issue is column that I didn't mention in the question because I thought it wasn't necessary but it is. I might ask this question again with all the details later on. Thank you for your solution because it almost works. But doesn't fully work because of a mistake I made.

Comment: I asked this question again. It would helpful if you could provide me a solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680953/combining-results-from-two-tables-into-json-data-updated-question