# Combining results from two tables into JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

[I asked a similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680376/combining-results-from-two-tables-into-json-data) but didn't include the column `book_no` in the question and since the solution that I wanted had to include this column to give me the proper JSON structure, the solution that I got didn't work because of this. Hence I'm re-posting this with the proper information.

I have two tables, `words` and `paragraph`. The `words` table is as below:

```
+----+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
| id | book_no | paragraph_no | word_no |   word  |
+----+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
|  1 |    1    |       1      |    1    |  hello  |
+----+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
|  2 |    1    |       1      |    2    |  how    |
+----+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
|  3 |    1    |       1      |    3    |  are    |
+----+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
|  4 |    1    |       1      |    4    |  you    |
+----+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
```

And the `paragraph` table is as below:

```
+----+---------+--------------+-------------------+
| id | book_no | paragraph_no |     paragraph     |
+----+---------+--------------+-------------------+
|  1 |    1    |       1      | hello how are you |
+----+---------+--------------+-------------------+
```

I want all the columns from the `words` table WHERE `book_no` is 1 and the paragraph column from paragraph table with the same WHERE clause all in one JSON results. Something like this:

```
{
    "1": [ <-- this is paragraph_no

        "words": [

            {
                "id": "1",
                "word_no": "1",
                "paragraph_no": "1",
                "word": "hello"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "word_no": "2",
                "paragraph_no": "1",
                "word": "how"
            },

            // and so on...

        ],

        "paragraph": [

            {
                "paragraph": "hello how are you"
            }

        ]

    ]
}
```

Please excuse my mock-up but I need something similar to that. My current PHP code to only get the words are:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM words WHERE book_no = 1");

$data = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $data[$row['paragraph_no']][] = $row; // paragraph_no from 'words' table

$API_RESULT = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

echo $API_RESULT;
```

Which outputs only the words like this:

```
{
    "1": [ <-- this is paragraph_no

        {
            "id": "1",
            "word_no": "1",
            "paragraph_no": "1",
            "word": "hello"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "word_no": "2",
            "paragraph_no": "1",
            "word": "how"
        },

        // and so on...

    ]
}
```

How can I get my desired JSON output?

Comment: Could you offer an SQL export so that we are able to set your project up in MySQL or post the `print_r` output of `$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` for both `words` and `paragraphs` here? Otherwise helping you comes with a huge effort to duplicate your whole project and database structure.

Comment: @Johannes sorry for the late reply but here's a pastebin link with both the words and paragraph table export code. https://pastebin.com/raw/t3sGNaWB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining results from two tables into JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680376/combining-results-from-two-tables-into-json-data)

Comment: your question is a duplicated of another question ypu posted that has **an accepted answer**. It the problem is the same please edit your original question to explain why the solution posted is not valid . If this is another different issue then post it as a different topic

Comment: I apologise for the downvote, but I will retract it if this second question is modified (my experience is that once an answer is accepted, any requests for useful amendments nearly never get done). Rather than merely editing the question to indicate it is "updated" from the last one, it may be better to link to the old one, and then to explain what was missing.

Comment: @halfer I edited the question with proper reasoning. Let me know if it's okay.

Comment: Yep, thanks - looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code produce the output you need?

```
$result_w = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM words;");
$results_w = $result_w->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$words_per_paragraph = [];
foreach($results_w as $key => $row) {
    $words_per_paragraph[$row['paragraph_no']][] = $row;
}

$result_p = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM paragraph;");
$results_p = $result_p->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$data = [];
foreach($results_p as $key => $row) {
    $p_no = $row['paragraph_no'];
    $words = [];
    if(array_key_exists($p_no, $words_per_paragraph)) {
        $words = $words_per_paragraph[$p_no];
    }
    $data[$p_no] = [
        'words' => $words,
        'paragraph' => $row
    ];
}
```

Content of `$data` (I haven't added any words to paragraph 2 for testing purposes):

```
{
   "1":{
      "words":{
         "id":"4",
         "book_no":"1",
         "paragraph_no":"1",
         "word_no":"4",
         "word":"you"
      },
      "paragraph":{
         "id":"1",
         "book_no":"1",
         "paragraph_no":"1",
         "paragraph":"hello how are you"
      }
   },
   "2":{
      "words":[

      ],
      "paragraph":{
         "id":"3",
         "book_no":"1",
         "paragraph_no":"2",
         "paragraph":"I'm fine and you?"
      }
   }
}
```

Maybe you can change your database table structure to get everything in one statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why is it only showing the last word? The output you posted shows the same thing. It should actually show all the words in the paragraph and not just the last one.

Comment: Because I made a mistake and forgot a `[]` in this line `     $words_per_paragraph[$row['paragraph_no']][] = $row;`. As a result, the index was always substituted and not extended. Not it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked! I really appreciate your help on both the questions that I asked:)